# Inserting an SQL query string into an SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to insert an SQL query string into my database, but I always get an error because of the single quotes `''`. I can't just double them `''''`, because then I can't execute the SQL query which is stored in the SQL database. Here is an example:

```
"INSERT INTO selections(selection_name, selection_sql, selection_besitzer, selection_sichtbarkeit, selection_standardSelektion)"
            + "VALUES ('"
            + "TestName"+"', '"
            + "Select * From customer where customer_adressnummer like '%1%';"+"', '"
            + "Select all from customer where X"+"', '"
            + "private"+"', '"
            + "0"+"')");
```

My question is: How can I insert this query into my SQL database without changing the String?

After I insert it I want to read it with my program and then execute the query based on the String in my database.

Here's the error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Select * From customer where customer_adressnummer like '
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3374)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2543)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1737)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2022)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1940)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1925)
    at toolhouseserver.ExecutionThread.run(ExecutionThread.java:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why do you trying to insert these string into column having type of **double** (as it is clearly said by exception)?

Comment: I dont know why this error appears. The column in my table is varchar(500). And the error is cuz '%1%'.

Comment: Try to escape apostrophes in the query you're inserting: `+ "Select * From customer where customer_adressnummer like \'%1%\';"+"', '"`

Comment: Can you tell me how i could do this in Java before insert (check String for '' and add \ insert and on Select remove them? Are the \ insertet into db?

Comment: use `String.replace`  something like `"Select * From customer where customer_adressnummer like '%1%';"+"'.replace("'", "\'")`. Backslashes will not be inserted into DB, it is escaping for MySql.

Comment: Use a prepared statement, or escape single quotes; for most databases this is done by doubling the single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprisingly, the probability of encountering SQL injection issues is rather high when trying to use dynamic SQL to insert SQL strings into an SQL database. Save yourself the grief and just use a parameterized query, like this:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO selections (selection_name, selection_sql, selection_besitzer, selection_sichtbarkeit, selection_standardSelektion) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, "TestName");
ps.setString(2, "Select * From customer where customer_adressnummer like '%1%';");
ps.setString(3, "Select all from customer where X");
ps.setString(4, "private");
ps.setString(5, "0");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you explain me how i can use this in an Client / Server environment?

Comment: The Java code above would be part of the application that runs on the client. The Connection object `conn` would connect to the database server by specifying the server details (name or IP, port, etc.) in the JDBC connection URL. A simple web search should provide you with many, many examples.

Comment: No i dont mean this. I know this. Currently i have this: Client connect to my own software server and then connects to the database server. The advantage is, that my client knows nothing about the database, i can make the database reachable from outside the lan without the insecure problem, that some one could send some sql-commands to my db.